# Back 3 activities and fields not blank android

Tags: android

I have 3 activities and want it to be possible to fill in a form on the activity after a 1 button takes me to the second activity that calls for his third activity. In the third activity I choose a value and want to go directly to the 1st activity but want the 1st activity is in the state it was in when it comes out.

I have this in 3th activity:

```
Intent selectFavorite = new Intent(view.getContext(), FirstsActivty.class);
selectFavorite.putExtra("Data", Info);
selectFavorite.putExtra("SUB", favoriteListArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("sub"));
selectFavorite.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

When i return the fill is blank :s

Comment: You have to take a look at the methods of an activity....in particular onResume and onNewIntent()...

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% there is a different and more reliable way to accomplish what you desire. If by any chance the reason you are going to `SecondActivity` and `ThirdActivity` is to get some input values for the `FirstActivity's` form, then you should consider doing this not in a different Activity, but using dialogs or similar. That way you will avoid having to unnecessarily manage more activity's lifecycle overridden method than what you actually need.

If you agree with me and you don't know if you should use dialogs, or action bar menu items or similar for what you want to accomplish, try checking out the Android design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html